# Line to Polygon Spatial Join

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, data

I understand how to join these two, however, I am having some issues. I am attempting to join a set of lines to a polygon that I have drawn. I want the polyline attributes to join to the limited table for the polygon. Basically I have some routes that run through the drawn polygon, and I want the polygon table to show the attributes of the affected lines to display in the table.

I would guess the spatial join is the way to go, but when I join, the data does not migrate into the table. It shows little data, and no select-able features. I have all data projected properly.

Comment: Forgive me, ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: No worries buddy :)

Comment: You either have to use the One To Many option to duplicate the polygon for each route or use the Join Merge rule on all fields you want, set the fields to text and 255 characters and add a delimiter to get attributes from all lines on to the polygon.  If no features are produced by the tool at all, try selecting all of the features in two layers in Desktop and use the layers as inputs to the tool.  Sometimes that works.